# Passing cookies and waiting for selector

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have two problems with my script. The first one is it's sometimes so fast with logging in that going to another page afterwards is broken, how can I fix this? Sometimes I have to re-run the script in the hope it will pass the cookies. The second issue what I have is that it's not waiting for the selector and not clicking on it as well.

```
 numb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Documentation](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagewaitfornavigationoptions) suggests to do this when logging in:

```
await Promise.all([
  page.waitForNavigation(), // The promise resolves after navigation has finished
  page.click('a.my-link'), // Clicking the link will indirectly cause a navigation
]);
```

> The second issue what I have is that it's not waiting for the selector and not clicking on it as well.

The element is probably not present on the page, or the target page is not what you expect it to be. Be sure to check with screenshots and/or headful mode.

Comment: Do I have to add the whole code block for every url to be clicked? For about the second issue. When a new page is added it has a countdown and after for example two hours the selector button is shown making it clickable and redirecting to a a new page.

Comment: By the way do I have to add everything in that promise block?

Comment: The `Promise.all` block makes sure all of actions inside of it are made, in no particular order. This is probably not what you want. As for the second issue, please create another question for it as the logic for solving it is entirely different.

Comment: i've made a new post regarding the other issue and posted more information about it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65719779/trying-to-find-out-how-to-wait-until-the-countdown-is-gone-and-push-on-that-butt